# Syntax highlighting suddenly different

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed recently that my vscode started acting a bit funny. Highlighting/changing colors on certain variables seemingly out of nowhere that are really throwing me off (lot of changing colors on return variables, bolding objects etc. A friend of mine is using the same color theme and we compared to make they were different and sure enough, mine has a bunch of whacky stuff going on.

I'm not sure what I did, I have been trying to figure this out for days with no luck, have tried to delete my JSON.workbench color theme settings to no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the same OS and versio? Maybe some random extension or config.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of VSCode ships with "semantic highlighting". Search your settings for the word `semantic`, and turn it off, and everything should go back to normal.

Comment: this did it thank you

Comment: no problem, if you want, you can click the check mark at the left to indicate the other users that this answered the question.  this turns it green so it's easier to see while browsing