# VSCode: TS/JS Language Features disable syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

since I updated my VS Code to 1.34.0, every variable- and function name is red. Is there any way to disable it? It looks normal when I disable the whole TS/JS Language Features package, but the support is disabled too. I Don't want that.

Image before update:

[image: Image before update]

Image after update:

[image: Image after update]

Comment: there is no issue for that dont worry just code !!! this is just suggestion not an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax highlighting suddenly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678198/syntax-highlighting-suddenly-different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First type the following command:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to turn on the command palette> <kbd>enter</kbd> "Generate Color Theme".

You should be able to see a json with different color settings. Choose the type you want to edit and restart it afterwards.

reference pic:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In all methods you will need to open the User Settings editor. To do this:

Click File > Preferences > Settings
Now expand "Text Editor"
Click on "Suggestions"
Click "Edit in Settings.json"
Now you will have the "{} User Settings" tab open. The pane on the left is the defaults and the pane on the right is where you can edit these settings. You will need to place the updates inside of the "{ code here, }" then click save.

Method 1, update the suggestion delay so you can still have tips but they don't appear unless you hover over the element for some time.

1
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000,
Method 2, disable the hover function. You will still be able to use CtrlR + K and CtrlR + I as needed.

1
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
Method 3, disable completely. You don't want or need these tips and you want them to go away forever.

1
"editor.parameterHints": false,

That's it, your done!