# Strange Java Highlighting in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[strange highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuiiW.png)

The highlighting for my .java files in VS code is very strange. I did not have this issue until recently, although I cannot think of any changes I made or new extensions I installed.

I have all of the extensions from Microsoft's "Extension Pack for Java":

- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat  v1.28.1
- Debugger for Java  v0.56.1
- Test Runner for Java  v0.40.1
- Maven for Java  v0.44.0
- Project Manager for Java  v0.23.4
- IntelliCode  v1.2.30

I tried restarting the program as well as uninstalling and reinstalling the extensions, to no avail. There are no preceding errors. Has anyone encountered this and found a fix?

Comment: You should probably include a full list of the extensions (and their versions) that you are using so it isn't guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for your case as mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/lw1o9x/comment/gpheszn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60678382) can be:

1. Open setting and search for "Semantic Highlighting"
2. By default it has the value "configuredByTheme". Set it to false

Another possible solution will be to change the theme you are using.

For more information you can read the following:

- Semantic highlight guide from the official docs of VSCode [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide)
- This issue openned on Jun 14, 2022 [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152032)
- Syntax Highlight guide from the official docs of VSCode [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)

Comment: The first solution worked, thank you. Are there any highlighting features that will no longer work I should be aware of?

Comment: @fndrplyr It should be safe to disable it. In the [official wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview) on github they mention that `Syntax highlighting colors the text based on lexical rules` whereas `Semantic highlighting enriches the syntax coloring based on symbol information from a language service that has the full understanding of the project.` plus `Currently semantic highlighting is only offered by TypeScript, JavaScript as well as JavaScript in HTML. More languages will adopt.`